# How to convert a string in an unknown date format into a python datetime object

Tags: python, datetime, datetime-format, strptime, python-dateutil

I'd like to convert this list of strings of various unknown date formats to a python `datetime` object. For example:

```
strings = ["today", "tomorrow", "next Friday", "June 4th", "04/11/2022"]

convert_to_date(strings[0])
>>> 2022-04-08

convert_to_date(strings[1])
>>> 2022-04-09

convert_to_date(strings[3])
>>> 2022-04-15
```

I tried several methods but found that:

- `dateutil.parser` only works for dates like `04/11/2022`
- `time.strptime` and `arrow` both require me to specify the format
- `regex` would be too complicated and may not work for all scenarios

Is there any library or function that would allow me to do something like this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert "unknown format" strings to datetime objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13258554/convert-unknown-format-strings-to-datetime-objects)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any library or function to do the thing you're asking to.

Here's some sample code to help you out (in python)

```
import datetime

def crazyDateToStandard(crazyDate):
    today = datetime.date.today()
    if(crazyDate=='today'):
        print("Today's date:",today)
    elif(crazyDate=='tomorrow'):
        tomorrow = today + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        print("Tommorow's date:",tomorrow)

#shows today's date
crazyDateToStandard('today')
#shows tommorow's date
crazyDateToStandard('tomorrow')
```

I have implemented a basic functionality here, its now up to you to figure this code out and ask yourself.

- What does each of these functions do?
- How i can use it?
- How can i implement it to my algorithm?

Comment: I can't tell if this answer is a "troll" answer or not. But there's already a library called [date-util](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) which has a parser module which can achieve what the question is asking.